# Groovy-Create instance on declaring the object type

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a Classes

```
Class LifeCycle{

  Activity  obtainPo
  Activity  bookTicket

}

Class Activity{
   String name
   string actor
}
```

**Objective**

on declaring the object of type `Activity` in `Lifecycle` class new instance of activity class should be created where name = parameter name (i.e obtainPo and bookTocket etc) 
like

`new Activity('obtainPo')`
actor can be null

how to achieve this in groovy and grails?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work provided this happens when you instantiate LifeCycle class object and make sure that other properties of LifeCycle (if any) are set in the constructor.

```
class LifeCycle{

  Activity obtainPo, bookTicket
  def anotherParameter

   LifeCycle(){
    //set another parameters first
      anotherParameter = "something"

    this.getProperties().each{
       if(!it.value){
         this.setProperty(it.key, new Activity(name:it.key))
       }
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: Well if that's what you are asking for. Not sure if I understood your question well. Would be great if you could have been more clear in your question.